# Download facebook videos from link in swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, alamofire

I am working on a swift application in which users have a link of videos like facebook etc and if the user wishes to download that he can just put a link in `UITextfield`  and download it. The code I tried is

```
func downloadAndSaveVideo(videoUrl:String?,videoName:String) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        guard let myUrl = videoUrl else {
            print("Invalid Url")
            return
        }
        Alamofire.request(myUrl).downloadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
            print(Progress)
            self.progress_view.progress = Float(Progress.fractionCompleted)
        }).responseData(completionHandler: { (responce) in
            if let data = responce.result.value{
                print(data)
                let documentUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                let videoUrl = documentUrl.appendingPathComponent(videoName)
                do {
                    try data.write(to: videoUrl)
                    print("done")

                }catch
                {
                    print("error")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This code is working fine if I use a playable link like [this](https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4). but if try to put facebook link like https://www.facebook.com/pagename/videos/962353737470453/ or youtube I am unable to download that video
can someone help me to how to download such videos or convert facebook video share link to watch or downloadable link so that I can download videos directly from my app.

Comment: You can use the Graph api for facebook video. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/video

Comment: but i don't need any user info from facebook. user has the link i just wish to download that.

Comment: As far as I know, you can not as Facebook content can only be downloaded through their api's.

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook. you must use the api for any data.

Comment: @luschn you mean something from facebook api? like graph api

Comment: of course, the graph api. > https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/

Comment: have you found your answer @Ptech1